# Why does my DLL not seem to be called?

Tags: windows, web-applications, dll, activex

I have a COM DLL, coded in Delphi. It should be invoked via an Active X control when a web page loads in MS IE (via soem JavaScript on the page).

Btw, this all works fine with an existing serial port interface, but I am recoding teh DLL to read from USB; all else is unchaged.

It works fine in the Delphi IDE, but not "in the field". The active X control should request it to read some input from a USB port and should then send that to the web page.

Reading from the USB device works, as I can open Notepad and see the value being written there.

The DLL will display a form, and a dialog box, and will write to the system debug trace. Since I am seeing none of these when loading the web page in MS IE, I think we can assume that Aective X control is not calling into the DLL.

- In MS IE I have enabled all Active X options.
- in c:\Windows\System32 (which is equivalent to c:\Windows\SysWOW64), I have `regsvr32.exe -u my_dll.dll` and then `regsvr32.exe  my_dll.dll` both of which the system announced to be successful
- I searched, and there is only one copy of `my_dll.dll` under c:\Windows
- and it has the correct size and date/time
- my `%path%` is `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;` for system and empty for user

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Or how I can go about tracking it down?

Comment: How do you load the ActiveX control in MSIE? Have you got any HTML or VBScript code for the webpage?

Comment: @PrahladYeri +1  JavaSCript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loading the ActiveX control in webpage through javascript, you will have to package the control for web deployment. See this example for how to do this in your javascript and check whether you have done properly it or not:

[Calling Activex Control 's Functions from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246391/calling-activex-control-s-functions-from-javascript)

Once you do the above thing correctly and open your website in IE, the web-page will at least "load" the ActiveX control. Beyond that, you can display message-boxes or write logs in your Delphi code to track down the actual coding issues.

Comment: +1 and thanks for replying. Sorry about the delay in getting back to you. I am not sure if I follow your referenced question. After calling `regsvr32` I have in my registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0004C7F4-BCCC-4476-8C0C-F045E2E0A1F7}` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib\{30F57A6B-D06D-4640-B19B-34A70EB64181}` and a few more references to the GUID which identifies my typelib. Do I need to do something more?

Comment: What code changes did you do to read it from usb? There is no need as the application need not be aware of underlying hardware, it just needs an object reference to latebind to.